# Hashmap memoization slower than directly computing the answer

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, memoization

I've been playing around with the Project Euler challenges to help improve my knowledge of Java. In particular, I wrote the following code for [problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), which asks you to find the longest Collatz chain which starts at a number below 1,000,000. It works on the assumption that subchains are incredibly likely to arise more than once, and by storing them in a cache, no redundant calculations are done.

Collatz.java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Collatz {
    private HashMap<Long, Integer> chainCache = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

    public void initialiseCache() {
        chainCache.put((long) 1, 1);
    }

    private long collatzOp(long n) {
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            return n/2;
        }
        else {
            return 3*n +1;
        }
    }

    public int collatzChain(long n) {
        if(chainCache.containsKey(n)) {
            return chainCache.get(n);
        }
        else {
            int count = 1 + collatzChain(collatzOp(n));     
            chainCache.put(n, count);
            return count;
        }
    }  
}
```

ProjectEuler14.java:

```
public class ProjectEuler14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collatz col = new Collatz();
    
        col.initialiseCache();
        long limit = 1000000;
    
        long temp = 0;
        long longestLength = 0;
        long index = 1;
    
        for(long i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
            temp = col.collatzChain(i);
            if(temp > longestLength) {
                longestLength = temp;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(index + " has the longest chain, with length " + longestLength);
    }
}
```

This works. And according to the "measure-command" command from Windows Powershell, it takes roughly 1708 milliseconds (1.708 seconds) to execute.

However, after reading through the forums, I noticed that some people, who had written seemingly naive code, which calculate each chain from scratch, seemed to be getting much better execution times than me. I (conceptually) took one of the answers, and translated it into Java:

NaiveProjectEuler14.java:

```
public class NaiveProjectEuler14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int longest = 0;
        int numTerms = 0;
        int i;
        long j;

        for (i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++) {
            j = i;
            int currentTerms = 1;

            while (j != 1) {
                currentTerms++;
    
                if (currentTerms > numTerms){
                    numTerms = currentTerms;
                    longest = i;
                }
    
                if (j % 2 == 0){
                    j = j / 2;
                }
                else{
                    j = 3 * j + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Longest: " + longest + " (" + numTerms + ").");
    }
}
```

On my machine, this also gives the correct answer, but it gives it in 0.502 milliseconds - a third of the speed of my original program. At first I thought that maybe there was a small overhead in creating a HashMap, and that the times taken were too small to draw any conclusions. However, if I increase the upper limit from 1,000,000 to 10,000,000 in both programs, NaiveProjectEuler14 takes 4709 milliseconds (4.709 seconds), whilst ProjectEuler14 takes a whopping 25324 milliseconds (25.324 seconds)!

Why does ProjectEuler14 take so long? The only explanation I can fathom is that storing huge amounts of pairs in the HashMap data structure is adding a huge overhead, but I can't see why that should be the case. I've also tried recording the number of (key, value) pairs stored during the course of the program (2,168,611 pairs for the 1,000,000 case, and 21,730,849 pairs for the 10,000,000 case) and supplying a little over that number to the HashMap constructor so that it only has to resize itself at most once, but this does not seem to affect the execution times.

Does anyone have any rationale for why the memoized version is a lot slower?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the initial capacity of the Hashmap?

Comment: Also your hashmap is just an array, why not just use array for that, it will be faster, no autoboxing involved.

Comment: @krzyk Yeah, as I mentioned in my penultimate paragraph, I tried increasing the initial capacity to ((key,value) pairs stored)/0.75 (0.75 is the default load factor) and there was no change in execution time.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to see what's taking them time? The answer given is probably correct but as ever of your want to know why something is slow then measure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some reasons for that unfortunate reality:

- Instead of containsKey, do an immediate get and check for null
- The code uses an extra method to be called
- The map stores wrapped objects (Integer, Long) for primitive types
- The JIT compiler translating byte code to machine code can do more with calculations
- The caching does not concern a large percentage, like fibonacci

Comparable would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int longest = 0;
    int numTerms = 0;
    int i;
    long j;

    Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++) {
        j = i;

        Integer terms = map.get(i);
        if (terms != null) {
            continue;
        }
        int currentTerms = 1;

        while (j != 1) {
            currentTerms++;

            if (currentTerms > numTerms){
                numTerms = currentTerms;
                longest = i;
            }

            if (j % 2 == 0){
                j = j / 2;

                // Maybe check the map only here
                Integer m = map.get(j);
                if (m != null) {
                    currentTerms += m;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else{
                j = 3 * j + 1;
            }
        }
        map.put(j, currentTerms);
    }
    System.out.println("Longest: " + longest + " (" + numTerms + ").");
}
```

This does not really do an adequate memoization. For increasing parameters not checking the `3*j+1`  somewhat decreases the misses (but might also skip meoized values).

Memoization lives from heavy calculation per call. If the function takes long because of deep recursion rather than calculation, the memoization overhead per function call counts negatively.